# Verificação do login com arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Olá! 
Eu estou a tentar fazer um código que permite a verificar se um dado email e password se encontram dentro de determinados arrays, até agora este código funciona, contudo não consigo fazer com que o código detete erros como: se o email estiver no array mas nao coincidir com a password, soltando assim um alert.

```
function Entrada_login() {
            var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
            for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
                if ((email == emails[i]) && (password == passwords[i])) {
                    i = i;
                    alert("funciona");

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Obrigada!!

Comment: Podia colocar na pergunta o **array** que faz as comparações!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode só adicionar um `else if`? Por exemplo:

```
function Entrada_login() {
    var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
        if ((email == emails[i]) && (password == passwords[i])) {
            i = i;
            alert("funciona");

            break;
        } else if ( (email == emails[i]) ) {
            i = i;
            alert("achou o email mas a senha nao confere");

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu tentei, mas apartir desse momento, ele começa a dar sinal de erro no div em que faz chamada a esse código. Por isso fiquei na dúvida se é do facto de ser dentro de um loop ou se tem a haver com outra coisa.

Comment: @Morango20 bom o código funciona https://jsfiddle.net/k7oujLma/ , pode ser alguma outra coisa, qual erro retorna?

Comment: Acho que afinal o meu código não funcionou porque no processo devo ter apagado um } e isso dava-me Unexpected Error, mas agora o teu código já fê-lo funcionar. Muito obrigado!! Tenho de começar a estar mais atenta a estes pormenores.